# Chrome For Mac AND windows -- Print using system dialog @page properties ignored

Tags: css, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap

I found a very odd problem printing in Google Chrome for Mac that I am trying to fix. When using "Print Using System dialog" option the @page inside the print styles are ignored, which causes the page to be incorrectly printed. When printing via the built in chrome print dialog it seems to work ago.

In windows Chrome, the system dialog and the regular dialog both ignore the @page properties.

The only reason I am even defining @page properties because my version of bootstrap defines these and I want to overwrite them.

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@page
{
    margin:10cm 10cm;
}
@media print
{
    @page
    {
        margin:0 !important;
    }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Working example:

http://blastohosting.com/chrome_bug/

Comment: It is possibly related to that bug [Bootstrap: Grid stacks when printing in IE 11 or Chrome 34](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12078) and [Chromium: Printed length of html element greater than defined in the css size of element.](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=273306)

Comment: I looked at these links...while similar it is not exactly what I am having.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried several approaches and found one that works with my version of Chrome (32). You have to set the value of the @page margin inside the print media query to 0 without !important, any other value will trigger the bug:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@page
{
    margin:10cm 10cm;
}
@media print
{
    @page
    {
        margin:0;
    }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked! Do you know why !important doesn't work?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I found that the issue also affects IE up to and including version 11, tested with the latest Opera and it does the same thing (the latter is not surprising given that it uses Blink, the same layout engine as Chrome). Not sure if it affects Safari as I don't have a Mac.

Comment: But at least we have a workaround..Maybe it is a feature and not a bug?